# Keras always predicting the same output

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, prediction

Keras will always predict the same class for every input i give hm. There are currently four classes.
News, Weather, Sport and Economy.

The training set consists of a lot of different texts, where the class is the same as its topic. There are a lot more texts classified as News and Sport, than there are texts for Weather and Economy.

- News: 12112 texts
- Weather: 1685 texts
- Sport: 13669 texts
- economy: 1282 texts

I would have expected the model to be biased towards Sport and News, but instead it is completely biased towards Weather with every input beeing classified as Weather with at least 80% confidence.

Just to add to my confusion: While training the annotator will reach accuracy scores from 95% to 100%(sic!). I guess I am doing something really stupid here but I don't know what it is.

This one is how i call my classifier. It runs on python 3 on a Windows pc.

```
with open('model.json') as json_data:
model_JSON = json.load(json_data)

model_JSON = json.dumps(model_JSON) 
model = model_from_json(model_JSON)

model.load_weights('weights.h5')

text = str(text.decode())   
encoded = one_hot(text, max_words, split=" ")

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
matrix = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix([encoded], mode='binary')

result = model.predict(matrix)

legende = ["News", "Wetter", "Sport", "Wirtschaft"]
print(str(legende))
print(str(result))

cat = numpy.argmax(result)  
return str(legende[cat]).encode()
```

This one is how I train my classifier. I omitted the part where I fetch the data from a database. This is done on a Linux VM.
I already tried changing the loss and activation around, but nothing happened.
Also I am curently trying to use more epochs but up to now that hasn't helped  either.

```
max_words = 10000
batch_size=32
epochs=15

rows = cursor.fetchall()

X = []
Y = []

# Einlesen der Rows
for row in rows:
    X.append(row[5])
    Y.append(row[1])

num_classes = len(set(Y))
Y = one_hot("$".join(Y), num_classes, split="$")


for i in range(len(X)):
    X[i] = one_hot(str(X[i]), max_words, split=" ")

split = round(len(X) * 0.2)     

x_test = np.asarray(X[0:int(split)])
y_test = np.asarray(Y[0:int(split)])

x_train = np.asarray(X[int(split):len(X)])
y_train = np.asarray(Y[int(split):len(X)])

print('x_test shape', x_test.shape)
print('y_test shape', y_test.shape)

print(num_classes, 'classes')

#vektorisieren
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
x_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_train, mode='binary')
x_test = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_test, mode='binary')

#klassenvektor zu binärer klassenmatrix
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

#model erstellen
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(max_words,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=1,
    validation_split=0.1
    )

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    verbose=1
    )

print('Test score', score[0])
print('Test accuracy', score[1])

#write model to json
print("writing model to json")
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

#save weights as hdf5
print("saving weights to hdf5")
model.save_weights("weights.h5")
```

Comment: It's very very likely that your model is indeed predicting sports for everything. Are you sure you're interpreting the four classes in the correct order? You might have inverted things between `y_train` and `legende`.

Comment: This is possible. But what confuses me is that the Classifier has an accuracy of nearly 100%. Anyway I will first go and properly normalize the data. It is worth a try,

Comment: It might be interesting to count how many elements in `y_train` belong to which class immediately before `fit`.

Comment: @Junge, I'm experienced with `Tokenizer` but maybe you are trying to predicate on `batch` and therefore result contains the `predictions` for the first batch (32 default size)?  what is the shape of `result` var?

Comment: Okay there was this funny thing happening, where I did use one_hot on the Y variables. since one hot is not collision free, a collision happened. He coded everything but "Weather" as 1 and "Weather" as 2. So now he could reliably predict everything to be a 2. I fixed that and now he pretty much always predicts "News" but thats a thing I might get under controll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tip that *@Daniel Möller* gave me I found out what the problem was. His tip was to look at how many instances of each Class are contained in your training set.

In my case I found out, that hashing your classes with One_Hot is not smart, as it will sometimes encode multiple classes with the same number. For me One_Hot encoded nearly everything as a 1. This way Keras learned to only predict 1.

Comment: I used a different way of encoding.
Please don't ask wich one, as I really don't remember anymore.